# UWP XAML UserControl Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP XAML user control which might be contained in another user control or might not.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel  >
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind person.FirstName}"  />
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind person.LastName}" />
        <Button Command="{x:Bind OkClicked}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Content="OK"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public sealed partial class PersonView : UserControl
{
    Person person => DataContext as Person;
    public ICommand OkClicked
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(okClicked); }
        set { SetValue(okClicked, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty okClicked =
        DependencyProperty.Register("oKclicked", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public PersonView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And my person Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My parent View XAML View

```
<Grid>
      <local:PersonView OkClicked="{x:Bind viewModel.PersonOkClicked}"> 
      </local:PersonView>
</Grid>
```

lastly my peopleViewModel:

```
public class PeopleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private DelegateCommand _personOkClicked;

    public Person Person1 { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand PersonOkClicked { get => _personOkClicked; set => SetProperty(ref _personOkClicked, value); }


    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        PersonOkClicked = new DelegateCommand(PersonOkButtonClicked);
    }

    private void PersonOkButtonClicked()
    {
        // do something with person1
    }
}
```

The PersonView has a datacontext set to the model Person and a dependency property OkClicked which I handle in the parent ViewModel. This is firing correctly when the button is clicked. How do I get the whole Person object into the peopleViewModel Person1 property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found you can do if your using Prism and DelegateCommand and you want to pass an object to a viewmodel using Dependencyproperties and not another viewmodel.In your code behind:

```
//Code behind    

public ICommand okCommand
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(_okCommand);
    set => SetValue(_okCommand, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty _okCommand = DependencyProperty.Register("okCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomerDetailsView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyModel myModel { get; set; }

    public UserControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myModel = new myModel();
        DataContext = myModel;
    }
```

In XAML

```
<Button
    Grid.Column="0"
    Command="{x:Bind okCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Bind myModel}"
    Content="OK" />
```

In your ViewModel:

```
    public DelegateCommand<MyModel> myModelOkClick
    {
        get => _customerDetailsOkClick;
        set => SetProperty(ref _myModelOkClick, value);
    }
```

In viewmodel constructor

```
    myModelOkClick = new DelegateCommand<MyModel>(CustomerDetailsOk);
```

In viewmodel a method to handle the click and Model.

```
    private void CustomerDetailsOk(MyModel model)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In PersonView UserControl you can use **`RoutedEventHandler`** for binding click event instead of `ICommand`. I have Modified your code with few changes to get person1 in PeopleViewModel. Hope it helps.

//PersonView.Xaml

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="{x:Bind person.FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
      <TextBox Text="{x:Bind person.LastName,Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <Button Click="OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Content="OK"></Button>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

//PersonView.Xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class PersonView : UserControl
{
    Person person;
    public event RoutedEventHandler Click;
    public PersonView()
    {
       person = new Person();
       this.InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = person;
    }
    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
       Click?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

//MainView.Xaml

```
<Grid>
   <local:PersonView Click="{x:Bind viewModel.PersonOkButtonClicked,Mode=OneWay}">
   </local:PersonView>
</Grid>
```

//PeopleViewModel

```
 public class PeopleViewModel 
 {
    public Person Person1 { get; set; }
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {           
    }
    public void PersonOkButtonClicked(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Person1 = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Person;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes I see thanks. I read that you can use a DelegateCommand<T> and in the ViewModel  Public void PersonOkButtonClicked(Object obj) {.....  do you know how you would set up the view to do that?