# C# Analog Clock project custom control pictureBox issue

Tags: c#, custom-controls

Codes are working fine on form1. But when I transfer them to custom control, some error occurs with picture boxes, ''does not exist in the current context.'' I guess I have to create them but I don't know how to use components with custom controller and transfer them to the form designer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOka8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvoyO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j0kc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template with the XAML components you need by using user control. [User Control Example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32795.uwp-creating-user-control.aspx) [More example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062383/uwp-xaml-usercontrol-binding)

Comment: How can I do that with Custom Control and without using XAML